# How to add keyboard layout switcher to top panel?

Tags: keyboard-layout, panel

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04. I've accidentally removed the keyboard layout switcher from my top panel and I don't know how to get it back. Does someone on here have the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, problem solved. I restored the default keyboard layout settings and then re-added the additional keyboard layouts I need. Now the switcher has reappeared in the panel.